# I want to show records from a table having a date column from sqldatabase in dates order. How should I?

Tags: sql, date, sql-order-by

I want to show records from a table having a date column from sqldatabase in dates order. How should I?

Comment: What an odd question... What have you tried?

Comment: @mjv, perhaps English is not their native language?

Comment: @KM I'm quite aware and sensitive about language barriers. In fact I typically try and gap these as much possible.  In fact, my question was asked in that spirit: if the OP were to post a snippet of code, or a web page where he's been or whatever else, it may help us all understand the very nature of his quest.  If all he/she needed is to read about ORDER BY, fluency English is not his/her only handicap...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY yourDateColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `order by`

```
select * from my_table t order by t.date_column
```

where `date_column` is a column name in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `dates_column`
```

optionally you can add DESC to reverse the order (newest to oldest):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `dates_column` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use an [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause on the column containing the dates.

Answer (score 0):

The database engine should handle the proper sorting for a date or timestamp column using an ORDER BY clause.  The only exception might be if your column is of type VARCHAR and holds a date of the form "mm/dd/yyyy".  Then you've got a bit more work to do.